# exclude WeekDate from the chart in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I have created in SSRS this chart here:

[image]

I have got a questions:

I would like to exclude some weekdates from my Chart. I would like to exclude the weekdate 52. I tried this here:

```
and WeekDate not like '2015-12-27'
```

but it not really works.
How can I exclude certain values?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not quite clear enough.  You tried that where?  In the dataset?  As far as I can see that is working as expected.  If you want to omit a date from the axis, I'd recommend that you calculate the week number in the SQL and add 51 to the weeks in the subsequent year, then tinker with the formatting options for the label.

Comment: Hard coding dates to exclude doesn't sound like a very good idea. Is there some logic to your exclusions, could you then include that logic in an expression within your report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the values used in your chart, just set the filter by right clicking on your chart and select `Chart Properties`.

[image]

In the `filter` tab add a new filter and set it like this:

[image]

In `expression` use the following:

```
=Switch(
Fields!WeekDate.Value="2016-01-02","Exclude",
Fields!WeekDate.Value="2016-01-03","Exclude",
true,"Include"
)
```

> In your case put the dates you want to exclude `"2015-12-27"`

In `Value` property use this expression:

```
="Include"
```

It will filter your report as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS reports select the relevant column in dataset using report design. Apply filter on this data (weekDate) as WeekDate < '2015-12-27'.

This will have effect on the report data display on the chart.